# Display a string character by character on textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way i can display a String character by character? like in old RPGs

I've tried this:

```
string text1 ="this is a text";
for (int i = 0; i < text1.Length; i++)
{
    textBox1.Text = "" + text1[i];                
}
```

but it only replaces the last character on the text box.

Comment: Just using a loop won't make any difference, it will appear instantly. You will have to use a timer (and properly concatenate the characters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do it:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  TypeText("this is a text");
}

private void TypeText(string text)
{
  textBox1.Clear(); // Make sure the textbox is empty

  Thread thread = new Thread(delegate() // Create a new thread which fills the textbox periodically
    {
      button1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { button1.Enabled = false; }); // Disables the button

      for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
      {
        int temp = i; // Cache variable because without this, an 'ArgumentOutOfRange' Exception will be thrown
        textBox1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate // Invoke to main thread
        {
          textBox1.Text += text[temp]; // Fill with next char
        });

        if (text[temp] != ' ') // This makes sure the user doesn't have to wait the double of the time when there is an empty space for the new character
          Thread.Sleep(500); // This will stop the seperate thread for 500ms. Won't block the main thread
      }

      button1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { button1.Enabled = true; }); // Reenables the button    
    });

  thread.Start(); // Start the new thread and continue the main thread
}
```

Comment: This one worked for me! im only having problems disabling the button im using this on, and then enabling it again after the text is complete. otherwise the text ends up all messed up if you click on it while it's writing.

Comment: @Bastidino How did you try it?

Comment: i tried different ways, now im trying with an if after the text it's done writing. if the button it's disabled, enable it. right after the  (textBox1.Text += text[temp];). but i throws me an exception, "InvalidOperationException. should i make a new question for this? thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int count = 0;
        string text1 = "this is a scrolling text";
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();               
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
            SetTimer(500);
        }
        private void SetTimer(int milliseconds)
        {            
            timer1.Tick+=new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Interval = milliseconds;        
            timer1.Start();
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(Object o, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (count < text1.Length)
            {
                textBox1.Text += text1[count];
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                button1.Enabled = true;
                textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

[image: Output1]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how that helps you.  You might want to add why you are doing this.  The issue you are having with your code is that your are not appending to the string.  Try this line instead:

```
 textBox1.Text += text1[i];
```

You need to clear textBox1.Text before you start (set it to "").

A better approach might be to print out the hex values so that non printing characters are easily seen.  You can do something like this:

```
string text1 ="this is a text";
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < text1.Length; i++) {
    sb.AppendFormat("{0:X} ", text1[i]);
    }
textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Reading Jeroen Vannevel makes me thing that you are trying to create a "typewriter" affect.  In that case try something like:

```
string text1 ="this is a text";
textBox1.Text = "";
for (int i = 0; i < text1.Length; i++) {
    textBox1.Text += text1[i];
    Thread.Sleep(250); // 1/4 sec delay
    }
```

This code was written modeled on the code given.  There is an implied expectation that this is run from the main UI thread.  This means that when you are sitting in a loop with a Sleep delay your UI will be unresponsive (since you are tying up the main thread).  You can overcome this by using the Invoke method on the Dispatcher object (of your App) and running the code on a different thread.  You should only Invoke the parts that are owned by the main UI (textBox1) in this case.

Comment: If this is what he wanted, then he can just do `textBox1.Text = text1`.

Comment: You won't notice 10ms. It should probably be more around 300-500. This will lock up the UI thread though.

Comment: I thought he might be looking for non-printing characters and was just showing the given code as an example.  I read your comment and appended to my reply.  I think you are probably right in how you read the question.  Yes, you are certainly correct this is probably a good place for a Dispatcher Invoke call on an async thread, but that seems to be getting into an "over-answer".

Comment: Up the delay to 250, 500 seems like a lot, but I don't really know what effect he's going for.

Comment: 500 is just half a second, it's still very fast. I've removed the downvote because it now answers the probable question, but you should probably add a warning for the UI lockup.

Comment: Should be -1, but I hope you can actually make it reasonable... `Thread.Sleep`? Are you seriously suggesting to put `Sleep` on UI thread??? (And don't put comments in code `Sleep(250); // 10 ms delay` looks very questionable)

Answer (score -1):

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + text1[i]
```

Answer (score -1):

To me it seems that you want to break a string into its characters, there are several ways to do that:

1 - String.GetChar() Method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.getchar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

2 - String.Chars property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
TextBox1.Text += MyString.Chars[i];
```

Then if you want to show them one by one with a delay or something like that, you can use timers as others have suggested.

Comment: This is not an answer and should be a comment at the very maximum. You provide no explanation why these matter nor does it solve a problem in the code.

Comment: A string allows indexed access to its characters using the `[]` operator, none of these methods are needed.

Comment: I think the question needs to be more specific. Because there are several different ways of breaking a string into char[].